# How to get all the categories/subcategories from a dynamic website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, playwright

I need to extract all the products from a site (https://www.hiperlibertad.com.ar/) that has multiple branches/stores.

The **main problem I have now** is that I need to find a way to adapt the code to be able to extract all the categories > subcategories that are on the site.

These can be seen from the main menu of the home page:

[Main menu with the categories > subcategories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGGGV.png)

I understand that the site generates the content dynamically with JavaScript. I was trying to use Playwright with Scrapy to get this listing but I could not.

**For this task I was instructed not to use Selenium.**

Any help on how to deal with the problem is appreciated!

I already have the code in Scrapy to extract the products from **a specific URL** (category/subcategory). The code works fine. I give it the URL and it extracts all the products from all the pages I have.:

```
import scrapy
import json

class HiperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hiper"
    base_url = 'https://www.hiperlibertad.com.ar/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search/hogar/muebles-de-interior'
    sc_value = '1'  # Default value is 1

    def __init__(self, sc_value='1', *args, **kwargs):
        super(HiperSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sc_value = sc_value

    def start_requests(self):
        url = f'{self.base_url}?O=OrderByTopSaleDESC&_from=0&_to=23&sc={self.sc_value}'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        products = data
        for product in products:
            name = product['productName']
            regular_price = product['items'][0]['sellers'][0]['commertialOffer']['Price']
            promotional_price = product['items'][0]['sellers'][0]['commertialOffer']['ListPrice']
            category = product['categories'][0]
            sku = product['productId']

            yield {
                'name': name,
                'regular_price': regular_price,
                'promotional_price': promotional_price,
                'category': category,
                'sku': sku
            }

        # Check if there are more products on the current page
        has_more_products = len(data) > 0

        # Extract current page range from the URL
        current_page_from = int(response.url.split('_from=')[1].split('&')[0])
        current_page_to = int(response.url.split('_to=')[1].split('&')[0])

        # Calculate the next page range
        next_page_from = current_page_from + 24
        next_page_to = current_page_to + 24

        if has_more_products:
            # Construct URL for the next page
            next_page = f"{self.base_url}?O=OrderByTopSaleDESC&_from={next_page_from}&_to={next_page_to}&sc={self.sc_value}"
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: You already use the API, so where exactly are you struggling?

Comment: Hi, I missed your comment, sorry! 
Yes, I can already interact with the API to get the data of some products (for example: the products of the 'base_url = https://www.hiperlibertad.com.ar/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search/hogar/muebles-de-interior' < the last part 'hogar/muebles-de-interior' represents the category/subcategory). With this code I can obtain products from that specific category/subcategory and for any given sc_value (branch/store number).

What I specifically need is to get all products, from all categories/subcategories, for a specific branch/store.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the approach here for getting all the products here and use only scrapy, by using sitemaps rather than going through categories and sub-categories.

Sitemap: https://www.hiperlibertad.com.ar/sitemap.xml

From there you can either take the data from the product page itself or get SKU from the page and call the API using the fetched SKU id.

API Page: https://www.hiperlibertad.com.ar/api/catalog_system/pub/products/search/?fq=productId: (Please replace  with a valid SKU)

Using PlayWright would have a similar overhead as selenium, and that'd be very comparatively slow.

Comment: Hey! How are you doing? Thanks for your answer!

The truth is that I didn't know about sitemaps. I was checking just now and apparently that option would be much better than the one I was using.

According to that sitemap, all the <loc> that appear seem to be the branches/stores, correct? Each of those URLs "product-1.xml", "product-2.xml" contain all the products in each branch/store I believe.

From all the product URLs, how can I get the SKU id? That part I don't understand yet. Then I can use that SKU and call the API, right?

Comment: @Kiko, no worries. <loc> tags with 'product' in URL refer to product sitemaps. From each of those product links, you can make a request to these links, and there are several places on product pages, where SKU is present. Then, pass that SKU in the API request.

Comment: I have been studying the sitemaps and I think all those product-1, product-2, ... product-16 are actually all the products for the whole site, but not for each of the branches/stores as I need them to be.